# DateFormatSymbol's behavior is different between Android and JRE 1.7

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I've made a jar for parsing a dateformat from text for JRE and Android.

Mostly It worked well. but when I try to parsing the following Chinese chars, It fails on Android and works on JRE. '五月' is May in Chinese.

> "06 五月 2014"

I used the following code to parse it

```
String input = "06 五月 2014"
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.CHINESE);
Date date = df.parse(input);
```

So, i started narrowing down the problems and got the following test cases.

on Android,

```
  DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.CHINA);

   String[] months = dfs.getMonths();// months[0] = 1月, months[1] = 2月 ...
   String[] ampm = dfs.getAmPmStrings(); // ampm[0] = AM ampm[1] = PM
```

on JRE 1.7,

```
DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.CHINA);

String[] months = dfs.getMonths();// months[0] = 一月, months[1] = 二月 ...
String[] ampm = dfs.getAmPmStrings(); // ampm[0] = 上午 ampm[1] = 下午
```

Why this happens? is this normal operation or am i missing something ?

Comment: Android != Java (that explains all, Android has never obliged itself to strictly follow Java in all issues, especially not in formatting resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the difference between Java and Android, your code is not even guaranteed to work on different Java VMs. The API documentation does not cover a formal specification of the different date formatters and you are not guaranteed that the formatted output from one Java VM can be parsed by another Java VM.

In this case, the localization database in the Oracle VM uses "五月" as the Chinese word for the month of May (literary: "fifth moon"). Your Android localization database uses "5月" (literary: "5th moon"), which is just as correct, but different.

Comment: thanks for your comments. seems it's normal operation.